# Integrate Extjs on frontend and Tapestry on backend

Tags: extjs, tapestry

I had a project that requires the use of Extjs as the frontend of my program and tapestry on the backend.

I am new with both, but still able to create the panels of forms on the frontend, however can anyone advise how would it be possible to link/integrate with the backend java side of tapestry such that the Extjs form panel would update the json data based from my backend?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of Tapestry are you using? T5 has very good support for Javascript

Comment: Yup, we are using T5 with Extjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a loot at the [HowTos](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowTos) and this wiki [entry](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToIncludeJavaScript) is a good starting point